# Cannot get the selected VCL theme styles

Tags: delphi, vcl-styles, delphi-10.1-berlin

In a Delphi 10.1 Berlin VCL application, in Project Options on the **Appearance** page I have added two styles to the default **Windows** style:

[image]

In the `FormShow` event handler I have this code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
begin
  // Show all available in application styles:
  ComboBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    ComboBox1.Items.Clear;
    for s in TStyleManager.StyleNames do
      ComboBox1.Items.Add(s);
    ComboBox1.Sorted := True;
    ComboBox1.ItemIndex := ComboBox1.Items.IndexOf(TStyleManager.ActiveStyle.Name);
  finally
    ComboBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

But unfortunately, at runtime the combobox contains only **ONE** item: The default Windows style:

[image]

So how can I get all the styles checked in Project Options?

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. I see all three style names in the combobox. The only difference I see is in your screen cap of the Appearance dialog; in mine, when I drop down the list it's sorted alphabetically and yours isn't. (Actually, that's not correct; if I exit the dialog and go back in, they're unsorted again and match yours.)

Comment: Is there maybe an additional option to activate/register the VCL styles?

Comment: No. I'm setting up a new machine, so I tested on a nice, clean Berlin install. There's absolutely nothing special you need to do. (I actually copied and pasted your code, and other than dropping the combobox on the form and adding Vcl.Themes to the uses clause I did nothing else.)

Comment: So why the VCL styles are not showing up in the combobox?

Comment: Now I have created a new clean VCL Forms application project and there it works! All 3 styles are showing up!

Comment: Now I have cleaned the other project where it does not work from all other components and all unneeded units. Now I have only the naked form with the combobox and it still does not work in this project. So there must still be some sort of incompatibility, but I cannot find it!

Comment: Ahh ... there IS a HIDDEN initialisation!! Now I have set the `Amakrits` style once as active style in Project Options. And from now on, even with the `Windows` set as active style, all 3 styles are showing up in the combobox. So the trick is to USE one of the additional styles at least once and then it works!!! It seems that this sets a flag somewhere to initialise the VCL Styles engine. But WHERE is this flag?

Comment: You need Vcl.Themes and Vcl.Styles in the dpr uses section.

Comment: @UweRaabe: I didn't need both. Vcl.Themes worked for me.

Comment: I do have `Vcl.Themes` in the uses list. But not `Vcl.Styles`. Is that needed?

Comment: Well, at least that is what the IDE includes when you select a non-Windows theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `TStyleManager` is a class in `Vcl.Themes` (which is included in the unit's `uses` clause) and the code example in the question does not produce any compiler error, `TStyleManager.StyleNames` does not give the correct results: It does not give back the additional VCL Styles activated in the Project Options dialog.

To make `TStyleManager.StyleNames` actually work, BOTH `Vcl.Themes` and `Vcl.Styles` must be contained in the `uses` clause of the PROJECT FILE (.DPR). (I am not sure whether this is mentioned somewhere in the documentation).

This has been confirmed by my tests. Thanks to @Uwe Raabe for the advice!

Comment: BTW and unfortunately, the "modality" bug is still not fixed: When changing the VCL Style inside a modal dialog, this dialog loses its modality!